# ASP.NET DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

How can i showing multiples rows of a database by a asp.net control like detailsview?

Comment: Please be more clear. Exactly what are you trying to do? Show us what you're doing, show us the result, and show us what's wrong with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple rows, the listview is very flexible and it is worth it to spend the time to become familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

try DataGrid

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For Multiple Rows you are better of with a:

**GridView**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx

**ListView**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx

**DataList** (I personally like the DataList a lot)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist(VS.80).aspx

**Repeater**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx

Those are controls that were made to show more than one record.